# Uber Rides/Python - How to configure Oauth w. Apache

Tags: python, apache, oauth, applescript, uber-api

I'm new to this so I apologize in advance. I am actually an AppleScript developer and would merely like to use Uber Rides.py into a script, and I have virtually no knowledge in Python. (Just looking for an 'easy' way to initiate a Uber ride within a more complex script using Homebridge and Siri).

I've built the py app but I don't know to get the Oauth code after using the authorization_code_grant.py script.

I will be the only user of this app (it's just for testing at home) so I'm not that worried about Auth but I understand it's a mandatory uber process. There's no frontend to the app (it's just the script running and responding to Siri requests via Homebridge) and no web page for the user to authenticate. The user will be myself so I just need a way to "get" the Oauth code that I then will use as part of the CLI/Python command within the Applescript.

I have two main issues:

1. Can someone give me a step by step on how to grab the code sent by Uber once the user has logged in and clicked on the authorized button? I seem to understand I should configure my Apache server to "receive" the code but I don't know how to? (If it helps I have set up an Horuku account but I'm not sure I need this considering Apache runs on my Mac, I just don't know how to configure it…)
2. When I try to use the authorization_code py (with the URI set to http://localhost:7000 but, to my knowledge, nothing runs on port 7000 at the moment, hence question 1) it generates the error below

**Error:**

```
>mediacenter$ python example/authorization_code_grant.py
Login and grant access by going to:
login.uber.com/oauth/authorize?scope=profile+request+history&state=MgnYJ18l7DxqbSYxkSfjrbGCL8BQAMg0&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauthswift.herokuapp.com%2Fcallback%2Fsiriuber&response_type=code&client_id=3Wk7zJbSLVCFCQ69UZvQJCZ_aBfHJBDu

>Copy the URL you are redirected to and paste here: 
oauth-callback/siriuber?state=MgnYJ18l7DxqbSYxkSfjrbGCL8BQAMg0&code=dK1ETADCaHcZCAbXnYKOSapetgexgj
Failed to request access token: UNAUTHORIZED. 
[ErrorDetails: 401 UNAUTHORIZED invalid_client] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example/authorization_code_grant.py", line 150, in 
hello_user(api_client)
File "example/authorization_code_grant.py", line 122, in hello_user
response = api_client.get_user_profile()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_user_profile'
```

I hope it kind of makes sense. I know I should spend some time getting to learn a "real" language but AS is (most of the time) perfect to bring different things together quickly and doing what I want!

Thanks in advance,
JC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same person from GitHub. After digging around, I came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36834041/5817707).

Basically there is probably a configuration issue in either your example/config.yaml or in your app dashboard. Make sure you configured both of those correctly. the example/config.yaml setup should be exactly like [this](https://github.com/uber/rides-python-sdk/blob/master/example/config.yaml) with the three values replaced. Make sure your redirect URL is the same as the one in your dashboard under "Authorizations" redirect URLs.

Did you install from source? As in did you clone it from the GitHub repo? Or did you install it using pip?

Hope this helps.

Comment: D'oh! So I didn't know that the URL didn't need to be VALID for the script to work (hence my Apache question) and I've realized a extra space in the config.yaml was all it took for the error to happen. "Successfully granted access token" now, so on to new adventures! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For sure, not a problem. If you could mark this question as "Answered" so anyone looking on the tag knows we figured it out, that'd be great. Have fun with it.